# Braces GroupRequiredMixin has no effect

Tags: django

I am using GroupRequiredMixin from braces.views trying to limit the access to some views to a specific group of users.

My view looks like this:

```
class InviteCompanyAdminView(LoginRequiredMixin, GroupRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = CompanyAdminInvitation
    group_required = u"staff"  # For the GroupRequiredMixin  
    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse
        form.instance.send_invite(self.request)
        return super(InviteCompanyAdminView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I am accessing the view with a user that doesn't belong to any group and yet the view is rendered. Any idea why?

My model looks like this:

```
class CompanyAdminInvitation(models.Model):
    user_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    user_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    user_title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    user_email = models.EmailField()

    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    company_country = CountryField()

    invitation_uid = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, unique=True, editable=False)
    has_been_used = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
    invitation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CompanyAdminInvitation, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.invitation_uid = str(uuid4())

    def send_invite(self, request):
        # TODO use a template instead of hardcoding the email
        subject = "Get started with your account!"
        message = "Hi, your link to start is %s" % \
                  (request.build_absolute_uri(reverse("users:admin_signup",
                                                      kwargs={"invite_id": str(self.invitation_uid)})))

        from_email = "no-reply@example.com"
        recipient_list = [self.user_email,]
        send_mail(subject=subject, message=message, from_email=from_email, recipient_list=recipient_list)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/"
```

Comment: What does your user model look like?

Comment: @AviMeir I'm having the same problem, how did you solve this?

Comment: @CésarBustíos coded it myself...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is the cause of the original posters problem, but this can be caused if testing with a superuser, which will ignore the group permissions in Braces (see [issue #105](https://github.com/brack3t/django-braces/issues/105) for django-braces)

Try testing with a non-superuser to fix this issue.